# What are the units of wavelet?

Tags: python, wavelet

I'm using the continuous wavelet transform on EEG data (originally in micoVolt) as follows:

```
coef, freqs = pywt.cwt(EEG_data, np.arange(0.5, 50, 0.5),'morl', 
sampling_period=sampling_period)
```

I know that the freqs's unit is Hz. What about coef?

Comment: normally coefficients are without a unit. If you scale a frequency, it stays a frequency, so the coefficient does not have a unit (or if you like to see what happens, it has the unit Hz/Hz).

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/cwt.html. The frequency as you suggested is in Hz. but the coef it says is simply the 'Continous wavelet transform of the input signal for the given scales and wavelet'. I hope it helps.

Comment: In fact, it does not really help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was suggesting that the unit of the coefficient would just be the unit of the input signal. Because according to the documents the coef is just the transformed version of the input signal. :)

Answer (score 0):

your `coef` are the transform has said [here](http://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/cwt.html). There is no unity it's a ratio of frequencies.

But I think what you need is to understand what a wavelet transform do :

In some way it's a generalization of the Fourier transform which will transform the Time-Amplitude space in a Time-Frequency space.

A wavelet transform will represent your signal as a pondered sum of your original wave translated and/or dilated

you can read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Comparisons_with_Fourier_transform_.28continuous-time.29) or [here](http://www.jhuapl.edu/techdigest/views/pdfs/V15_N4_1994/V15_N4_1994_Sadowsky.pdf)